# How to reduce Fedora's disk size in VMware player

Tags: linux, fedora, vmware-player

I'm new to Fedora 14, vmware player. After getting Fedora up and running in VMware player. The disk size was 2.7 GB. After three hours of working with it, the disk size has bloated to 4.3 GB. I havent added software to account for the near doubling in size.

How do I reduce the size back to 2.7GB range or lower. Im new to Fedora and superuser controls. Im removing more software than adding software.

Is this a VMWARE problem or Fedora problem?

Answer (score 1):

Go to root directory (`cd /`) and then check your disk usage using commands `df` and `du`, so you'll know what's using up all that space.

If space taken up inside virtual machine is much lower than space taken up by the VM on your real computer, perhaps you've told VMware to allocate more disk space on installation than needed. Check VMware's hard disk settings for your VM. Specifically, preallocated space, current size, system free and maximum size.

Comment: thanks for helping out. Df dev/mapper says used 2744,000 avail 7020,000 dev/sda1 used 48,000 avail 420,000. So, im not using the 4.3 GB. So, i guess it VMware allocating the space and not recovering?

Comment: @user428862: it seems so; if VMware is set up to allocate more memory as needed, it will allocate more disk space that might not be used up really by the virtual machine. Even after you free up some disk space in your VM, VMware will play it "safe" and won't shrink automatically your disk space, since you would get mad if you found out one day that you have 5GB less available space than yesterday.

Comment: ok, Is there any way to shrink the 4.3 Gb, it wont fit on thumb drive. Or, should be using Virtual box.

Comment: @user428862: it can be done, but it's tricky. Take a look at [this SF post](http://serverfault.com/questions/76159/how-to-shrink-a-vmware-virtual-disk-vmdk) or google around for "VMware player shrink hard disk".

Comment: I tried converter, didnt work....It just kept cloning the orig without giving the option to shrink.... What I'm doing wrong... Will this problem recurr.